# Store excel data in a MySQL DB trough PHP using JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, vba, xmlhttprequest

I have two columns data in an excel spreadsheet that I want to store on a MySQL DB (locally hosted for the moment).

I'm converting my spreadsheet into a JSON string that I'm sending to a PHP code through XMLHTTP. Here is my VBA code :

```
Sub sendjson()
Dim json As String
Dim filed1 As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim data As String
Worksheets("param").Range("C1").Select

data = "{" + Chr(34) + "data" + Chr(34) + ":["

j = 2
Do While Not (IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 3)))
    j = j + 1
Loop

i = 2
Do While Not (IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3)))
    If i < j - 1 Then
    data = data + ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) + ","
    Else
    data = data + ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) + "]}"
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
Worksheets("param").Range("D1").Value = data

json = data

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objHTTP.Open "POST", "http://localhost/test/jsontomysql.php", False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send ("field1=" & json)
Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is the jsontomysql.php code :

```
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $entry){
        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO param (tck, value) VALUES(:tck, :value)');
        $req->execute(array(
            ':tck'=>$entry->tck,
            ':value'=>$entry->value
        ));     
    }
}
?>
```

And my MySQL DB has the following structure :

param{tck(VARCHAR255), value(real)}

When I run the code, nothing is happening. I'm pretty sure the issue is around : `$data = json_decode($json);`

In order to get things easier, I copy directly the JSON string in my php code, as following :

```
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
//$phpArray = json_decode($_POST['field1']);

$data = '{
    "u1":{"tck":"EUSA1 Curncy","value":0,005},
    "u2":{"tck":"EUSA2 Curncy","value":0,0049},
    "u3":{"tck":"EUSA3 Curncy","value":0,0048},
    "u4":{"tck":"EUSA4 Curncy","value":0,0047},
    "u5":{"tck":"EUSA5 Curncy","value":0,0046},
    "u6":{"tck":"EUSA6 Curncy","value":0,0045},
    "u7":{"tck":"EUSA7 Curncy","value":0,0044},
    "u8":{"tck":"EUSA8 Curncy","value":0,0043},
    "u9":{"tck":"EUSA9 Curncy","value":0,0042}
    }';

$phpArray = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { 
    foreach ($value as $entry) { 
        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO param (tck, value) VALUES(:tck, :value)');
        $req->execute(array(
            ':tck'=>$entry->tck,
            ':value'=>$entry->value
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

It seems I have an error at line 26 in my first foreach loop...

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\finance\jsontomysql.php on line 26
```

EDIT :

The problem must be between VBA and PHP because, when I do this, the SQL DB is well updated :

```
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
//$phpArray = json_decode($_POST['field1']);

$data = '{"u1":{"tck":"EUSA1 Curncy","value":0.005},"u2":{"tck":"EUSA2 Curncy","value":0.0049},"u3":{"tck":"EUSA3 Curncy","value":0.0048},"u4":{"tck":"EUSA4 Curncy","value":0.0047},"u5":{"tck":"EUSA5 Curncy","value":0.0046},"u6":{"tck":"EUSA6 Curncy","value":0.0045},"u7":{"tck":"EUSA7 Curncy","value":0.0044},"u8":{"tck":"EUSA8 Curncy","value":0.0043},"u9":{"tck":"EUSA9 Curncy","value":0.0042}}';
var_dump($data);

$phpArray = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($phpArray);

foreach ($phpArray as $u) {  
        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO param (tck, value) VALUES(:tck, :value)');
        $req->execute(array(
            ':tck'=>$u['tck'],
            ':value'=>$u['value']
        ));
}
?>
```

What is the issue ?
Thank you

Comment: How do you get the value of the variable $json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found :-). The problem was in the sending object and the separator used for my figures.

After having converted the "," into "." in my Excel spreadsheet, I had to figure out the sending vba object issue.

**The working codes are the following** :

The **VBA** Code : (converting the data into a JSON String and sending the string to my PHP Page)

```
Sub sendjson()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim data As String
Worksheets("param").Range("D1").Select

data = "{"

j = 2
Do While Not (IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 4)))
    j = j + 1
Loop

i = 2
Do While Not (IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4)))
    If i < j - 1 Then
    data = data + ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4) + ","
    Else
    data = data + ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4) + "}"
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
Worksheets("param").Range("E1").Value = data

'data --> php
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    serverURL = "http://localhost/finance/jsontomysql.php"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", serverURL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    objHTTP.send ("field1=" & data)
Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

My **PHP** Code & **MySQL** query :

```
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
// $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
// echo fwrite($file,$_POST['field1']);
// fclose($file);
$data = $_POST['field1'];
$phpArray = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($phpArray as $u) {  
        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO param (tck, value) VALUES(:tck, :value)');
        $req->execute(array(
            ':tck'=>$u['tck'],
            ':value'=>$u['value']
        ));
}
?>
```

To make sure the string was received by the PHP Code, I was writing the results in a .txt file (=commented part in my code).

Now, the MySQL DB is well inserting the value in the DB.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the field you are posting `field1`, so that line would probably have to be something like:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['field1']);
```

You should also move your prepare statement out of the loops; you only have to prepare it once.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at what json_decode($json) is actually outputting? Are you getting the data back in a form that you were expecting to be able to iterate over it like you're attempting?

Simply try doing a print_r($json); to work on debugging the output as a quick verification.

It would appear json_decode is failing. In my testing, it's because your 'values' are not quoted.

Example:

```
<?php

$data = '{"u1":{"tck":"EUSA1 Curncy","value":"0,005"},"u2":{"tck":"EUSA2 Curncy","value":"0,0049"},"u3":{"tck":"EUSA3 Curncy","value":"0,0048"},"u4":{"tck":"EUSA4 Curncy","value":"0,0047"},"u5":{"tck":"EUSA5 Curncy","value":"0,0046"},"u6":{"tck":"EUSA6 Curncy","value":"0,0045"}}';

$phpArray = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) {
  print "$key\n";
  print "$value[tck]\n";
  print "$value[value]\n";
  print "\n\n";
}

?>
```

Output:

```
marks-mac-pro:~ mstanislav$ php data.php 
u1
EUSA1 Curncy
0,005


u2
EUSA2 Curncy
0,0049


u3
EUSA3 Curncy
0,0048


u4
EUSA4 Curncy
0,0047


u5
EUSA5 Curncy
0,0046


u6
EUSA6 Curncy
0,0045
```

Comment: If I quote my 'values', they are considered as string. I need to use float. But, I changed the "," into "." and now, my values are well recognised as float. But, the error is the foreach loop... Do you have an idea?

Comment: I edited my answer above. Actually, I copy directly my JSON string in the PHP code to see if my php/mysql code is working. Actually it is. The problem seems to be in the sending part from VBA, but I have no clue about it... Do you have an idea ? Thank you !